# How to get long lived access token from vkontakte?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, vk

I am using passport js for authenticating people in my node.js application. In case of vkontakte I got the access token which is valid for just one day? here is my code

```
passport.use(new VKontakteStrategy({clientID: '******',clientSecret: '********',callbackURL: "http://example.com/signin/vkontakte/callback",profileFields:     ['notify','friends','photos','notes','pages','offers','questions','wall','messages','offline']},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        console.log('vk profile: '+util.inspect(profile));
        console.log('refresh Token: '+refreshToken);
        profile.accessToken = accessToken.toString();
        return done(null, profile);
    });
}
```

));
`
Is there a way to increase the validity period? Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Set scope=offline in your token request

Comment: but I am sending that in my request(Please check the vkontakte stretegy parameters). So can you suggest the proper way to set this scope

Comment: When you send `scope=offline` you request long living Access Token. The field `expires_in=0` in the VK oauth response, indicates that long living Access Token was requested, it doesn't expire. There is no other way to increase the validity period by yourself, because it is defined by VK.

Comment: If using PHP SDK it can be done like this `$scope = array(VKOAuthUserScope::WALL, VKOAuthUserScope::GROUPS, VKOAuthUserScope::OFFLINE);` this will get the wall scope, group scope and return the long lived access token